# "Featured image" on Jekyll causing Google not to index text of page

Tags: seo, google-search-console, markdown

I am using Notepad theme on a Jekyll powered blog hosted on Github pages. The theme has an option to set "Featured Images". This basically means when you open a post, a big image (the featured image) with just the title appears, and on scrolling, this disappears bringing in front the post.

I love having this, but the problem is, the SEO is very poor in the posts where I use this featured image. The text written in the post doesn't get indexed at all. Only the description I provide get's indexed. The others are indexed very nicely.

When I do "Fetch as Google" in Search Console (Webmasters tools), I only see the featured image, so I am guessing maybe that may be the reason?

What can I do to improve or solve this? It would be great to hear your views regarding this.